# Can we send Tile notification from Desktop app on Windows 8?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

as we know, we could send out the toast notification from Desktop App (not store app) on Windows 8 per this link [sending toast notification from desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and also [code sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2). We are looking at if we could send the tile notification from desktop applications and I didn't find information on internet. So it seems to me that it is impossible. However I just want to confirm with expert here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct - tile notifications are not supported for Desktop applications.

In the Requirements section of the [`TileUpdater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208628.aspx) documentation, the class is marked as "Windows Store apps only".

Comment: Is there any MSDN link just to reinforce your answer?

Comment: @TiagoCardoso - I've updated my answer with MSDN documentation stating that tile notifications are for use in Windows Store apps only.

Comment: Just perfect, @NathanKuchta!